# What play's Action really is?

Tags: scala, playframework

In

```
val echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

It seems Action is a function, have one function type parameter, it's type is Request[A] => Result

In the doc:https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.html

It tell me Action is a trait:

```
trait Action[A] extends EssentialAction
```

"An action is essentially a (Request[A] => Result) function that handles a request and generates a result to be sent to the client."

so what the Action really is? a function, or a trait?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Scala, a function is indeed defined using a trait, for example

```
object foo extends (Int => String) {
  def apply(i: Int): String = s"hello $i"
}
```

or

```
val foo: Int => String = i => s"hello $i"
```

or

```
val foo = new Function1[Int, String] {
  override def apply(i: Int): String = s"hello $i"
}
```

all define a function we can call with `foo(42)`, which desugars to `foo.apply(42)`.

An action is

```
trait Action[A] extends EssentialAction
```

where [`EssentialAction`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/EssentialAction.html) is

```
trait EssentialAction extends (RequestHeader) => Accumulator[...]
```

where we see the `extends (RequestHeader) => Accumulator` syntax. Note that `A => B` is syntactic sugar for [`Function1`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html) trait, so we could write

```
trait EssentialAction extends Function1[RequestHeader, Accumulator[...]]`
```

Now an `Action` trait also has an [`Action` companion object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Action$.html) which takes a function argument `block` and constructs an `Action` with default request body:

```
Action.apply(block: (Request[AnyContent]) => Result): Action[AnyContent]
```

and this is in fact what is used when we write

```
Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```